# Screen resolution won't change no matter which way I try it

Tags: gnome, virtual-machine, manjaro, xrandr, wayland

Hello, I'm using Manjaro GNOME in a VM and I wanted to change the screen resolution to 1080p.
To achieve this I firstly used xrandr. Its a bit weird though, that the only output detected is "XWAYLAND0" and not "Virtual1". This is what I entered in the terminal:

```
~ $ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2567   1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~ $ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2567   1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~ $ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 1920x1080_60.00
```

But the screen resolution still does not show up in the display settings.

What I tried next was changing the GRUB screen resolution as shown in a YouTube tutorial.
I changed `GRUB_GFXMODE` in my `/etc/default/grub` to `1920x1080x32` and entered the command

```
~ $ sudo update-grub
```

But this also had no affect on my screen resolution.

How do I change my screen resolution?

Answer (score 2):

You're seemingly running Wayland.

`xrandr` is an X11 application and it cannot change the resolution of your Wayland compositor/session.

Please refer to https://arewewaylandyet.com/ (under "Output/display configuration tool"), [Wayland equivalent of arandr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564793/wayland-equivalent-of-arandr)

---

IMO Wayland is far from ready and I'd recommend switching back to Xorg in which case you can continue to use `xrandr`.